# Curl - Option -: is unknown; Wget - unrecognized option string

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab-ci, wget

The following works perfectly fine on my Mac, but doesn't work when run in a GitLab pipeline:

```
      curl --request POST \
      --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
      --header "Content-Type: application/json"\
      --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "'${EMAIL_TO}'"}]}],"from": {"email": "'${FROM_EMAIL}'","name": "'${FROM_NAME}'"},"subject": "'${SUBJECT}'","content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": "'${bodyHTML}'"}]}'
```

I receive the error message:

> "curl: option -: is unknown"

However, I'm not sure where this is coming from as, like I say, it works on my Mac.

Someone in another post suggested running wget instead:

```
wget https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY"\
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --post-data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "'${EMAIL_TO}'"}]}],"from": {"email": "'${FROM_EMAIL}'","name": "'${FROM_NAME}'"},"subject": "'${SUBJECT}'","content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": "'${bodyHTML}'"}]}'
```

This then came back with:

```
"unrecognized option '--------------------------------</p><p>Hi'"
```

Which is the first line of my $bodyHTML variable, which should be read as a string:

```
bodyHTML="<p>---------------------------------- AUTO EMAIL --------------------------------</p>"
```

Could someone advise how I can get around this either via curl or wget?

**EDIT:**

I tried the suggestion below of using JQ, though that currently gives me a 400 Bad Request error:

```
wget https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY"\
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --post-data "$(jq -n --arg email_to "$email_to" --arg email_from "$email_from" --arg from_name "$from_name" --arg subject "$subject" --arg bodyHTML "$bodyHTML" '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": $email_to}]}],"from": {"email": $email_from,"name": $from_name},"subject": $subject,"content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": $bodyHTML}]}')"
```

Comment: One note: `"'${bodyHTML}'"` should be `"'"${bodyHTML}"'"`. Right now if your bodyHTML has spaces in it the argument will be split up because those spaces are in an unquoted context so they're subject to word splitting. Indeed, that's almost certainly the whole problem.

Comment: ...even better would be to use jq instead of string concatenation to generate your message body, so it still works even if the body includes things that need to be escaped to be valid in JSON. Indeed, I'm 99% certain we already have Q&A describing how to do that; may just close it as a duplicate...

Comment: `--postdata "$(jq -n --arg email_to "$EMAIL_TO" --arg email_from "$EMAIL_FROM" --arg from_name "$FROM_NAME" --arg subject "$SUBJECT" --arg bodyHTML "$bodyHTML" '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": $email_to}]}],"from": {"email": $email_from,"name": $from_name},"subject": $subject,"content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": $bodyHTML}]}`

Comment: btw, don't use all-caps variable names -- those are reserved for variables that reflect or modify system behavior; variables with at least one lower-case character in their names are guaranteed not to unintentionally modify behavior of POSIX-defined tools.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy - very helpful and useful info. 
I tried your suggestion of using jq (your version was missing a quote or two and a closing bracket), but I'm getting a 400 error back: --post-data "$(jq -n --arg email_to "$email_to" --arg email_from "$email_from" --arg from_name "$from_name" --arg subject "$subject" --arg bodyHTML "$bodyHTML" '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": $email_to}]}],"from": {"email": $email_from,"name": $from_name},"subject": $subject,"content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": $bodyHTML}]}')"

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Storing the output of jq in a variable so you can compare it to the expected values before use is generally a good place to start.

Comment: It is a good place to start. Even if I put the output of JQ in a variable and confirm everything looks OK, it still just does not work. The errors are non-descriptive. I want to send a simple HTML email. What I have works via Bash on my Mac. When placed in a GitLab pipeline (the runner of which uses an Ubuntu image), the exact same command doesn't work. I asked this question to receive a working answer; the linked suggested answer doesn't resolve the issue at all. Can this please be re-opened?

Comment: The hint was intended to suggest that you [edit] the question to add the relevant value (as well as a hand-built working example to compare it against). By the way -- asking because I've made this mistake myself -- any chance the bearer token might have expired between the test runs?